# Autocomplete list event stoppropagation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, propagation

I have a Panel on click of button hide/show 
Under Panel Input area, used auto complete to show data.

```
$('body').click(function () {
   $('.bk-panel').hide();
});
```

On click of body panel hides also it works fine with inner elements / On click of inner element it doesn't hide as I have used this :

```
$('.bk-panel').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But On Input were I used autocomplete jquery > on click of ul li list which comes it hides my panel div.

I have tried propagation on all of these classes  > ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  / Nothing seems to work

Comment: Got the solution: 
If any one will require solution :

$('.autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete, .ui-menu-item, #ui-id-1021').click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

Answer (score 0):

Another easier alternative:

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    var container = $('.bk-panel');

    // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    // ... nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/azq4wjdj/